# GET & POST with ViewModel having 1 list property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Okay so I want the user to be able to edit and add more medical info cards. I am able to do it for just 1 medical info object but making it to be able to handle a list of medical info objects seem to be harder than I thought. I'm sure there is a solution to this without resorting to hacky buggy tricks. My attempts so far hasn't worked. An example of my latest Attempt is below.

My current error I get when i try to save any changes:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'B4B.Models.Profile', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'B4B.Models.WizardViewModel'.

Model

```
public class WizardViewModel
{
    public Profile _profile { get; set; }                       
    public MedicalInfo _medicalInfo { get; set; }               // Each profile can have many medical infos
    public List<MedicalInfo> medInfoList { get; set; }          // So here I decided to make it a list of medicalinfos
}
```

Controller

```
    // GET: Profiles/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        WizardViewModel wizardViewModel = new WizardViewModel();
        Profile profile = db.Profiles.Find(id);
        wizardViewModel._profile = profile;
        wizardViewModel.medInfoList = profile.MedicalInfos.ToList();          


        if (profile == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        if (CurrentUser.Profiles.Contains(wizardViewModel._profile))
        {
            return View(wizardViewModel);
        }


        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
     }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "_profile, medInfoList")] WizardViewModel wizardViewModel, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           ....
            wizardViewModel._profile.Admin = CurrentUser; // comes back null so i manually reset
            db.Entry(wizardViewModel._profile).State = EntityState.Modified;            //Adds profile object into database


            foreach(var mi in wizardViewModel.medInfoList)
            {
                var medicalInfoDB = db.MedicalInfoes.Find(mi.MedicalInfoID);

                mi.ProfileID = wizardViewModel._profile.ProfileID;
              db.Entry(medicalInfoDB).CurrentValues.SetValues(wizardViewModel._medicalInfo);
                db.Entry(medicalInfoDB).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Comment: Is the error message not self explanatory ? Your view is strongly typed to a collection of your view model (and expecting your action method to pass it), but your action method is not sending the same type, It is sending a single object of your view model.!!!!

Comment: Long night... thanks! I should probably take a break if i'm missing things like that